# Setting up remote git repo for pushes

Tags: git

I have the following remote directory:

```
/home/darren77
```

I use `git init --bare` to set up the directory as a repo

which adds `.git` directory

Then on local pc I have directory that is my workspace

```
c:/testAccount/
```

I then try to clone the remote repo to set up to push:

```
$ git clone ssh://darren77@tinbad.com/home/darren77.git
```

But I get the following:

```
stdin: is not a tty
fatal: '/home/darren77.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from the remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong? There's so much talk about this but no one place that actually details it in absolute basic format for users new to git, not that I can find anyway.

Comment: The user darren77 might not have read access to the `.git` directory.

Comment: How is ssh authentication working? username/password or key based

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git clone ssh://darren77@tinbad.com/home/darren77/.git
```

The `git init --bare` could have created a `.git` folder inside `/home/darren77`

A more appropriate name for that repo would be:

```
cd /home/darren77
git init --bare myrepo
```

That will create a `myrepo.git/` folder (a folder ending with `.git`)

Then you would clone it with:

```
git clone ssh://darren77@tinbad.com/home/darren77/myrepo.git
```

Comment: that is correct, it has! Although everywhere else I;ve searched has the same dir structure and they say remove trailing slash

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have updated the answer to show you a more appropriate name for your bare repo.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not make a home directory a repository. Make a subdirectory called `repos` or something and then a bare repository inside that with the name of your project and a `.git` suffix. The path would be `/home/darren77/repos/project0.git`. Inside this directory would be the contents of the `.git` directory (i.e. a bare repository).

`git init --bare` shouldn't create a `.git` directory. If it is, something is wrong.

After verifying these, try `ssh darren77@tinbad.com` to see if you can connect to the server properly. If yes, consider using this syntax (it's what I use). 
`git clone darren77@tinbda.com:/home/darren77/repos/project0.git`